# Validate two lists together using Stream

Tags: java

Wish to compare, two (object) lists for

1. Not null
2. Not empty
3. Equal Size
4. Nth Element Field values are same

Possible?

```
String A = "one,two,three|four,five,six|seven,eight,nine"
String B = "three,six,nine"

List L1 = List.of(A.split("\\|"));
List L2 = List.of(B.split(","));
```

Give object of List L1, if the third sub value of an element matches with element of the List L2.

Comment: When you say compere, do you mean you want the result to be boolean?

Comment: `listOne.equals(listTwo)`?

Comment: Don't use uppercase names for variables. Variables, methods and fields should all start with a lowercase letter. Also, please format your code using the `{}` button.

Comment: Uhm... You just completely changed the question, IMHO. How does the lower part of the question correlate with the upper part?

Comment: What `List` are you talking about? `java.util.List` has no `of()` factory.

Comment: The point of raising this query is to get the result using streams. You could see it in the title. I agree, I missed it in the description. Regret. Hope, now we could discuss, shall we? Let me know where is it misleading...

Comment: @JoseMartinez When you say compere, do you mean you want the result to be boolean? - Result as a List

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak listOne.equals(listTwo)? - Using Streams

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answered the question when it was:

> Wish to compare, two (object) lists for
>     1. Not null
>     2. Not empty
>     3. Equal Size
>     4. Nth Element Field values are same
> Possible?

Since then, it was significantly changed...

---

Seems like you can go with `Objects.equals(list1, list2);`

1. When only one of the lists is null, it returns false.

2./3. When the sizes are different, it will return false.

4. When the elements differ, it will also return false.

In any other case, it will return true.

Disclaimer: This works for the standard Lists in the Collections Framework. There might be other implementations which implement `equals()` differently (and therefore behave differently when applied to `Objects.equals()`).

Comment: do we have `Objects` class in java ? I never seen it. Can you share the link ?

Comment: @Ravi yes, we do - `java.util.Objects`

Comment: Frankly saying, I wasn't aware

Comment: @Ravi `java.lang.Object` is actually the base class of every single Java class

Comment: @Sirmyself I think you mean `java.lang.Object`

Comment: Objects.equals returns true for 2 null objects. Wouldn't that be against the askers first condition?

Comment: [**`java.util.Objects`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) was added in Java 7. Click link to see javadoc. It is entirely different from [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: @Sirmyself I'm aware of `Object` class

Comment: @Aniket_Sahrawat true, I was basing my comment on  Jaroslaw Pawlak's one

Comment: are there any Stream's involved here? I thought the question was about a solution which uses Streams.

Comment: @yamass That was a good try. I respect your knowledge. However, the point of raising this query is to get the result using streams. You could see it in the title. I agree, I missed it in the description. Regret. Hope, now we could discuss, shall we?